# How to Integrate ABBYY in Ionic 4?

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic4, ionic-native, abbyy

I want to integrate `ABBYY Real-Time Recognition` plugin in my Ionic 4 app. 
Here is the [link](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/abbyy-rtr).

Their documentation is quite incomplete. Visited this [cordova npmjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-abbyy-rtr-sdk-sample) link also but go error while building android app.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration
>   ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
>    Could not find :abbyy-rtr-sdk-1.0:.

Any help would be much appreciated thanks!

Comment: I think my tutorial helps you https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vIzZe8irmRs

Comment: @PareshGami That's cool. A big thank you!!!

Comment: Let me known if anything happens in that or post bugs there.

Comment: @PareshGami Since I'm also making that app for `ios`, i'll surely let you know if I got any doubt or bugs. Also write a short answer to this question so that I can accept it. Again thanks a lot!!!!

Comment: I will do tutorial next for abbyy for iOS sooner. Once i get time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get workout of it with doing below in project folder.

Download sdk from rtrsdk site and extract it.

You will find `libs > abbyy-rtr-sdk-1.0.aar` file on it.

We have to put it under `platforms > libs > android > abbyy-rtr-sdk-1.0.aar`

Now try to make build.

Please watch video tutorial for same.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vIzZe8irmRs